# Flags for g++ static link when using -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs -nostdlib

Tags: gcc, g++, static-linking

I've been trying to find the proper .a's and related flags for statically linking an app or SO under Linux. I know -static exists, but I can't use it as there's one specific SO I must link to.

To put it another way, I'm looking for the appropriate flags to statically link everything, except for a specific SO.

Thanks.

Comment: you really need to state _what_ you want to have statically linked and _what_ dynamically.

Comment: Thanks, I've added a commend to @Kurt S's answer.

Answer (score 2):

At my workplace we use -Bstatic and -Bdynamic but they are options to the linker ld. You can specify them with gcc using the -Wl option.

`g++ -o app -Wl,-Bstatic -llib1 -llib2 -llib3 -Wl,-Bdynamic -llib4 app.o`

Above shows command line for linking with **lib1**, **lib2**, and **lib3** as static libraries and **lib4** as a shared object library.

Comment: Thanks, that's helped. Though libc/m/dl are still dynamic for some reason. I'm linking against the required dynamic libfoo.so, which dynamically links against lib/c/m/dl. Is that the reason that my app is not statically linking them in? Is there a way to force libc/m/dl to statically link in the app, yet still dynamically link libfoo.so?

Comment: joe, do static versions of libc, m, and dl exist? Typically they'll only have shared versions available so that the OS vendor can update them independently of your app.

Comment: @JosephGarvin they do yes, mine are in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu. Though I'm sure I'll use g++'s -static flag in other projects, right now it does 110% of what I need, it statically links too much heh. I realize that c, m, and dl are practically guaranteed to be on the system, I'm just trying to be super cautious.